# Using CTEs to show transitive relationships in data

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm working on an archaeological database which includes a couple of tables describing the spatial relationship between stratigraphic units. It's quite simple -- a unit is either above or below another unit. For this I have a table that records unit_1, unit_2 and the type of spatial relationship between them (above or below). I also want to generate a view which also records the transitive counterpart. In other words, if unit A is above unit B, I also want a temporary row stating that Unit B is below unit A.

This is how my CTE looks currently. The error I get is "ERROR:  relation "matrix_cte" does not exist", so this is probably not the way to do it. But the idea here is that when the relation is 'above' (which is the same as 1), the INSERT command should add a new line to the table created where the two units are reversed, and the relationship is below (or 2). Any help greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
WITH matrix_cte  (unit, related_unit, relationship)
AS (SELECT lookup_unit,
lookup_unit_2,
lookup_unit_relationship

FROM register_unit_matrix)
INSERT INTO matrix_cte(unit, related_unit, relationship)
SELECT lookup_unit_2, lookup_unit, 2
FROM (register_unit_matrix

INNER JOIN matrix_cte ON ((register_unit_matrix.lookup_unit = matrix_cte.unit)))
WHERE relationship = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `INSERT` into CTE. CTE is a logical table, it is an alias to a result set. You can `SELECT` from CTE.
Not really sure what you are trying to achieve there.

> ERROR: relation "matrix_cte" does not exist

This error messages means that you can `INSERT` only into the relations (tables). CTE is not a table, it is not a permanent object in the database and your database doesn't have a table called `matrix_cte`.

---

To generate all relationships, both direct and inverse you can `UNION` two result sets together. If your original table has only relationships in one direction, then you can use `UNION ALL` and the query will be faster. I mean, if original table never has two rows for the same pair of units:

```
unit1, unit2, 1
unit2, unit1, 2
```

then you can use `UNION ALL` below. If original table may have such duplicates, you should use `UNION` to remove extra duplicates.

```
-- all direct relationships as they are
SELECT 
    lookup_unit,
    lookup_unit_2,
    lookup_unit_relationship
FROM register_unit_matrix

UNION

-- inverse all relationships 
SELECT 
    lookup_unit_2,
    lookup_unit,
    CASE WHEN lookup_unit_relationship = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS lookup_unit_relationship
FROM register_unit_matrix
```

You can put this query above into a view, or use as is.